# Not able to install e(fx)clipse plugin in eclipse luna 4.4.0

Tags: javafx, java-6, eclipse-luna, efxclipse

My system configuration is

1. Jdk 1.6_45
2. Eclipse Luna 4.4.0

When i try to install e(fx)clipse 2.1.0 from eclipse market place it is giving me error.

What an I missing? Where can I read about the setup in order to start working with this framework?

Comment: I can't find the exact requirements at the moment but Luna + Java 1.6 is probably too old. The current e(fx)clipse requires Java 8 and Eclipse Mars. Look at http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html

Comment: Java 1.6 is definitely too old. I'm not even sure you can run JavaFX under Java 1.6, at least not without reverting to a pretty old version (which may not even be available) and doing a lot of low-level config work. Why are you using 1.6?

Comment: Because we are already using jdk 1.6 for our old project ...now there is requirement to include javaFx app into jsp page so i am trying to build my javaFx app with jdk 1.6 and deploy it to our existing web project.

Comment: @James_D: If i use jdk 1.8 to create and Build javaFx app jar and deploy it into existing jdk 1.6 web project ...so is it work ?

Comment: You would need a jre 1.8 on the client side. JavaFX is a client-side technology: I don't know what it means to "deploy it into existing 1.6 *web project*". At any rate, support for jdk 1.6 stopped a long time ago.